# Remove similar from foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Trying use array_unique but this did not help, since not all fields are repeated for me.
My array:

```
'Rows' => 
  array (
    0 => 
        array (
        'HotelId' => 94852,
        'OfferId' => 858080496,
        'OfferIdStr' => '858080496',
        'Price' => 2762,
    ),
    1 => 
      array (
        'HotelId' => 94852,
        'OfferId' => 858080497,
        'OfferIdStr' => '858080497',
        'Price' => 3000,
    ),
```

And my try:

```
$allHotels['Rows'] = array_unique($allHotels['Rows'], SORT_REGULAR);
```

Changed flags, didn't help either (SORT_NORMAL, etc...).
It deletes absolutely everything, i need to ignore the HotelId replay, only first need.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need to display all records without repeating the HotelId key

Comment: So for your input data you would only display the first record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete duplicated entries based solely on the `HotelId` value, it's probably easiest just to iterate over the array, storing the seen `HotelId` values and deleting the current entry if it's `HotelId` value has already been seen.

```
$seenHotels = array();
foreach ($allHotels['Rows'] as $key => $hotel) {
    if (in_array($hotel['HotelId'], $seenHotels)) {
        unset($allHotels['Rows'][$key]);
    }
    else {
        $seenHotels[] = $hotel['HotelId'];
    }
}
print_r($allHotels);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AtmDb)